# Single submit button with multiple form using service

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I have one requirement where should be able to submit multiple form with single button with different component.It is possible to implement it?  . This is I provided a demo code and [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-layout-and-routing-tmulkt) as your reference.

**Submit Button Component**

**HTML**

```
 <div class="form-group">
   <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="submitBtn()">Save</button>
</div>
```

**Component.ts**

```
  @Output() submitBtnClickEvt: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
    submitBtn() {
    console.log('Submit clicked');
    this.submitBtnClickEvt.emit({details: { clicked: true}});
  }
```

**Form Component**

**One**

**HTML**

```
<div class="formContainer">
  <h5>One</h5>
<form [formGroup]="contactForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <input type = "text" name = "fullName" placeholder = "Your full name" formControlName="fullName" >
  <br/>

  <input type = "email" name = "email" placeholder = "Your email" formControlName="email" >
  <br/>

  <textarea name = "message" placeholder = "Your message" formControlName="message" ></textarea>

</form>


</div>
```

**Component**

```
createContactForm(){
    this.contactForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      fullName: [''],  
      email: [''],
      message: ['']
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
      console.log('Your form data : ', this.contactForm.value );
  }
```

**Two**

**HTML**

```
<div class="formContainer">
  <h5>Two</h5>
<form [formGroup]="contactForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <input type = "text" name = "fullName" placeholder = "Your full name" formControlName="fullName" >
  <br/>

  <input type = "email" name = "email" placeholder = "Your email" formControlName="email" >
  <br/>
  <input type = "password" name = "password" placeholder = "Your password" formControlName="password" >


</form>


</div>
```

**Component**

```
 createContactForm(){
    this.contactForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      fullName: [''],  
      email: [''],
      password: ['']
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
      console.log('Your form data : ', this.contactForm.value );
  }
```

> Edit

**Submit Component**

```
  constructor(
    private submitService: SubmitService
  ) {}


  ngOnInit() {
    combineLatest([
      this.submitService.setFormConfDetailValue$.asObservable()
    ])
    .pipe(
         tap(([ formTwo]) => {
           if (formTwo) {
             console.log('Form data: ', formTwo);
           }

    })
    ).subscribe();

  }

  submitBtn() {
    console.log('Submit clicked');
    this.submitService.submitForms$.next();

  }
```

**Submit Service**

```
import { EventEmitter, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class SubmitService {

public submitForms$: Subject<any> = new Subject();
public setFormConfDetailValue$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  constructor() {console.log("test from service") }

}
```

Comment: You cannot do it using submit. However, you could do it from a function fired on click of the button and then grab the values from both forms inside of that click event.

Comment: Could you give me example?

Comment: Sure give me a couple of minutes.

Comment: Take a look at this. It's rough around the edges and could be refactored/optimized. I'd look at making component 1 and component 2 child components of the view that has the save button so that this could be done via inputs and outputs rather than a shared service.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-layout-and-routing-tmulkt

Comment: I've test... but nothing happen

Comment: One second the Stackblitz didn't save

Comment: I can't get Stackblitz to work. You should be able to copy paste the code from the answer into your Stackblitz and it should work.

Comment: this is all possible using a service but i think you need to flesh out your requirements a little more... do you want each form component to handle the submission on their own? is their some master form handler?

Comment: I want each form component to handle the submission on their own

Comment: In that case I'd refactor my code so that the emitted event on submitForms$ (Subject to do it non-hacky as mentioned below) triggers a call to submit the form. I'm assuming you want each form to utilize a service to make an HTTP request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

StackBlitz isn't letting me save my changes so I'm posting the pertinent code here. As I said above I think I would change the layout so that inputs and outputs could be used with submit, one and two components.

submit.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output, OnDestroy } from "@angular/core";
import { SubmitService } from "./submit.service";
import { combineLatest, Subject } from "rxjs";
import { tap, takeUntil } from "rxjs/operators";

@Component({
  selector: "app-submit",
  templateUrl: "./submit.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./submit.component.css"]
})
export class SubmitComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() submitBtnClickEvt: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor(private submitService: SubmitService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
      combineLatest([
        this.submitService.setFormOneValue$.asObservable(),
        this.submitService.setFormTwoValue$.asObservable()
      ])
      .pipe(
           tap(([formOne, formTwo]) => {
             if (formOne || formTwo) {
               console.log('Form data: ', formOne, formTwo);
             }

      })
      ).subscribe();
  }


  submitBtn() {
    console.log("Submit clicked");
    // this.submitBtnClickEvt.emit({ details: { clicked: true } });
    this.submitService.submitForms$.next();
  }
}
```

one.component.ts

```
...
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private submitService: SubmitService)
...
ngOnInit() {
    this.submitService.submitForms$.subscribe(() => {
      this.submitService.setFormOneValue$.next(this.contactForm.value);
    });
}
...
```

one.component.ts

```
...
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private submitService: SubmitService)
...
ngOnInit() {
    this.submitService.submitForms$.subscribe(() => {
      this.submitService.setFormTwoValue$.next(this.contactForm.value);
    });
}
...
```

submit.service.ts

```
import {Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class SubmitService {

  public submitForms$: Subject<any> = new Subject();
  public setFormOneValue$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  public setFormTwoValue$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  constructor() { }

}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212360/discussion-on-answer-by-tuckerjt07-single-submit-button-with-multiple-form-using).

Comment: There are some pretty severe memory leaks all over this code as an FYI